# Google cloud IP no resolve with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

I create a instance VM in google cloud computer engine with a Wordpress with bitnami implementation, when i´m editing the site, ip is reached and dont work moretime.

Comment: Please share more details. Is this a problem with Wordpress itself, or with the VM? Is this problem even related to programming?

Comment: Hi, thanks to response, I think problem is caused by the VM, in deployment manager page i click on url and i get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Comment: Let me know if the provided Answer was helpful. I am happy to assist you in case of any further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below points can be taken into consideration for resolving your issue.

- Incoming **firewall** rules for your instance should be using **port 80** for **HTTP** and **port 443** for **HTTPS**. Ensure these ports are not used by another application or blocked by a firewall.

  **Console->VPCnetwork->Firewall**
- Check your **web server** status and **restart** if needed.

  To **restart** a Web server,try below commands based on your application.

> For **Apache**: Sudo service apache restart
>
> For **Nginx**: Sudo nginx apache restart
>
> For **Database**: Sudo mysql apache restart

- Make sure you have sufficient resources and database settings in your wordpress. It should be using ‘**wp-config-php**’.

> SSH session-> **sudo nano** **/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php**

- Another possibility is to **increase** the **memory limit** of PHP in **wp-config. php**. If you are using shared hosting, you may have to ask your hosting provider to increase your memory limit. This allows you to run heavy plugins successfully which helps wordpress site to run longer.
- Try bypassing **DNS issues** or recheck your **DNS configuration** and restart your VM instance. Directly access the IP address http://your-instance-ip and if it works then the problem is with your DNS.
- **Plugins**: Some plugins can cause the application to show a warning or directly crash. This is due to incompatibilities with the WordPress version or some special Apache requirements (such as using .htaccess files). Disabling or removing the conflicting plugin solves the issue.

For more information you can refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/).

**UPDATE:**

To fix a problem related to **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** you can try the below commands by referring to the [blog](https://david.aladegbaiye.com/bitnami-wordpress-err_connection_refused/) written by **David Aladegbaiye Patricks**.

- to stop and start systems: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start`
- to check all services running : `sudo service -status-all`
- to run the script to force start Apache: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Comment: Thanks. I comment you about that points:

Comment: - Firewall is OK. Allow in only wordpress, 80 and 443.
- Restarting web server. Apache throw error. nginx no exists. mysql restart ok.
- wp-config no exist path htdocs
- I can´t access to increase the memory limit
- I try show the web by external static IP and throw ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- I can´t get log in to see plugins installed.

Thanks again

Comment: Can you do a health check using the below link and let me know the output. [https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/)

Comment: Since you got an error related to Apache, can you check the below link and update accordingly [https://david.aladegbaiye.com/bitnami-wordpress-err\_connection\_refused/](https://david.aladegbaiye.com/bitnami-wordpress-err_connection_refused/)

Comment: I got it!! From David's post i run `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start` and wordpress works!!